# How to use a pretrained model stored as a .npy file?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am attempting to load and use a pretrained model on some sample images to learn more about it. The pretrained model I'm attempting to use is here: https://github.com/nikhilmaram/Show_and_Tell

They link to the pretrained model here: https://ucsb.box.com/s/vqcxockfzoxfqltrg4l619x1cfvnskog
But they don't exactly specify how best to use it.

Which when downloaded is a .npy file of what I assume is model weights. I have never used something like this before, so I'm trying to understand how I can load this sort of stored model into a tensorflow model that I can then use? I'm making some assumptions as tensorflow seems to be what they're using. Attempted to load using the below to at least understand what sort of data structure I am dealing with but without success.

```
import numpy as np

np.load('Documents/39999.npy')

ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments I am able to load the file with np.load as below, but am still not sure how to take a numpy array of weights and load into tensorflow.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.load('Documents/39999.npy',allow_pickle=True)
```

Looking at the structure of this file I get the following, which I'm not quite sure how to interpret.

```
data.dtype
Out[24]: dtype('O')

data.shape
Out[25]: ()
```

Edit 2:

```
type(data)
Out[6]: numpy.ndarray
```

When I do data.item() I get a long array printed out, sample below.

```
[[-5.75947622e-03,  4.07667161e-04, -5.18753566e-03, ...,
    8.14088504e-04, -4.34151705e-04,  1.14657767e-02],
  [ 4.41048900e-03, -3.57159856e-03,  3.01857502e-03, ...,
   -3.98184508e-02,  1.49278138e-02, -8.20163079e-03],
  [-2.44483184e-02,  2.32945569e-02, -2.34904625e-02, ...,
   -1.79554094e-02, -3.21781076e-02,  1.07798241e-02],
  ...,
  [ 5.12963720e-03,  2.35215593e-02, -3.53378877e-02, ...,
    3.48278917e-02, -2.01826524e-02,  2.35197158e-03],
  [ 3.45730968e-03, -1.26461498e-02,  1.03930170e-02, ...,
   -3.20292413e-02, -6.37839548e-04, -7.48459855e-03],
  [ 3.67492763e-03,  6.75461590e-02,  9.46969260e-03, ...,
    4.72220499e-03,  4.39464301e-02,  6.21765293e-03]]]],
```

dtype=float32)}

Comment: Did you try `data = np.load('Doc...npy', allow_pickle=True)`?  If that works, you can at least examine the `data` array.  Start by checking it `data.dtype` and `data.shape`.  That said, this will just be data or parameters (weights), not a function or code that you can plug and run.

Comment: That does allow me to load the file at least so that's good. I do also understand it's going to be weights that I need to convert into a tf model in some way, which is my ultimate goal. Some weird results when I do data.dtype I get dtype('O') and when I do data.shape I get ()

Comment: That's a single element object dtype array.  You can access that element with `data.item()`.  I don't know what it will be.  When you save a non-numpy array with `np.save`, it wraps it first in such an array and uses `pickle` on the non-numpy part(s).

Comment: @user2355903 - can you update your question with the contents and `type()` of `data.item()`?

Comment: @jakub I updated the question with those results.

Comment: @user2355903 - it looks like the output of `data.item()` is an array of network weights. If you know the architecture of the network, you can set the weights using this array. Do you know the architecture?

Comment: I believe the architecture is specified here, https://github.com/nikhilmaram/Show_and_Tell/blob/master/model.py